# How to design a class that can be reused in other projects

Tags: uml, class-design, reusability

We want a chair class for a game. 
How can we create this class so that it can work in another game too?
And by considering the solid principles.

Imagine for example, that we have 2 games: one is a poker game, another is a grand theft auto like game.  In the poker game the class should have an `id`, `playersited() : player` , `state : full` , `empty` , `reserved`. I can think of these properties right now.  But in the second game, the chair doesn't necessary need an `id` or a `playersited()` function. So how can I design this class that can be reused in another games?

Comment: I just don't get it.

Comment: which part don't you get?

Comment: Simple answer: Don't.

This seems to be a good case of were not to try to reuse / and over share.
Trying to be overly generic will cause added complexity and you will endup with a bad generic class instead of good specific one.

Read about `composition over inheritance` and go for that.

Comment: thanks,that was a straight forward answer.

Comment: @kigiri Based on just the title, yes.... You should write that as answer!

Comment: @Thomas what's wrong with the title?haven't you heard of reusable code?

Comment: The title is fine and only reading that I guess that @kigiri found the answer. Your description however is, hmm, not descriptive.

Comment: well,i'm so sorry.caus my english is not very well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for a generic game object that you could reuse in different games, but which might have different properties and different functions depending on the game.

#### Simple UML answer

If you're only looking at it from the UML perspective only, this design issue is simple:  draw a class `GameObject`, put in it the properties and operations that you want to be common.  Then in the model of your different games, just create a a specialisation using inheritance:  `PokerObject` and `GrandCloneObject` in which you'd add the game specific properties and operations.

But this apparent simplicity would hide a lot of difficult points when you start to design links with other classes (reusable or not), and even more when you start to look at their interactions.

#### Limitations of such a generic design

In addition you want a SOLID design.  The LSP will then reduce the reusability by forcing you to keep the reusable interaction between objects to rely only on common part.

If only 10% of the design is then really reusable in the end, and 90% is game specific,  you'll gain no advantage and just make the code more complex by splitting classes artificially. Here I'd joint @kigiri's comment:  "*JUST DON'T*"

#### A better approach

But if you're looking for is something really reusable at a higher scale, there is a solution if you look not at a `Chair`, "Weapon", "Item",  but at a higher level of abstraction.

And here,  I can only recommend you to read Mike McShaffry's *Game Coding Complete* book, that will introduce you a very powerful architectural pattern called the  [Entity Component System](https://medium.com/ingeniouslysimple/entities-components-and-systems-89c31464240d).

The Idea is to abandon deeply nested class hierarchies wiht very specific classes,  but prefer a very flat model with:

- **Entities**:  these are the main objects used in the game, whatever the game is
- **Components**:  these are owned by the Entities,  and represent either properties that an entity can have (e.g. LivePoints, Force, ...), or behaviors that the Entity shall have (e.g. renderFixedObject,  soundWhenClicked, etc..).

This design allows to develop highly reusable objects allowing to add game specific components on the top of reusable entities and components.